# Is the expectation of the median the median itself?

Tags: probability, expectation, standard-deviation, means, median

[image]

It doesn't make sense to me that |E[x] - m| = |E[X-m]|

Comment: The median is a (nonrandom) *number* hence yes, it is equal to its expectation.

Comment: More generally $E[X]-E[Y]=E[X-Y]$ so $|E[X]-E[Y]|=|E[X-Y]|$ and if $Y=m$ almost surely then $E[Y]=m$ too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E[X-m]=E[X]-E[m]=E[X]-m$ because $m$ is a constant. For instance, if $m=5,$ then
$E[X-m]=E[X-5]=E[X]-E[5]=E[X]-5.$
Similarly,
$E[X-\mu]=E[X]-\mu=\mu-\mu=0,$ a familiar fact.

Answer (score 7):

I think the underlying issue is an apparent confusion regarding the meaning of "median" in this question.  In the present context, the median refers to a property of the distribution of the random variable $X$, rather than a statistic of a sample drawn from such a distribution.  Both are called "median" (for brevity) but the latter is more precisely called the *sample* median.

To recap, $m$ is a **median** of a real-valued random variable $X$ when $$ \quad \Pr[X \ge m] \ge \frac{1}{2} \quad \textrm{AND} \quad \Pr[X \le m] \ge \frac{1}{2}.$$  Presumably, the question implies that $m$ is unique, in which case equality is observed.  Such a value is not stochastic:  it is a deterministic quantity that depends on the parametric distribution of $X$, just as $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are (when these exist).  Just because these may not be assigned a known numeric value does not mean they are random.

This is in contrast to the definition of a sample median, which is a statistic and therefore itself a random variable.

Comment: $\Pr[X \ge m] \ge \frac{1}{2}$, not $\Pr[X \ge m] \le \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: +1 I really like this answer in that it addresses the underlying confusion. I took the liberty of editing the definition of median in accordance with what Did says in the comment above.